# Create pagination on archive blog base on year

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pagination, blogs, archive

i need to create pagination for my archive page base on year on my simple blog website, build from scratch using codeigniter.

my posts table is like this:

```
id_post | title content | post_date | id_user
```

i have successfully create an archive list base on monthyear

the structure is something like this :

October 2012

- title - content
- title - content

November 2012

- title - content

December 2012

- title - content

January 2013

- title - content

February 2013

- title - content

but i need to display the archive base on year, so it must be something like this:

January 2012

- title - content

February 2012

- title - content
  March 2012
- title - content

April 2012

- title - content

May 2012

- title - content

June 2012

- title - content

and next page is year 2013, 2014, 2015..

So far this is my controller and model for testing the result data:

controller :

```
    $this->load->model('model_test');

    $arsip = $this->model_test->get_all();

    //print_r($arsip);
    foreach ($arsip as $time_period => $news_items)
    {
        //display bulan tahun atau display period yang udah di tentuin di model
        echo '<div class="date">' . $time_period . '</div>';
        echo '<ul class="press">';

        //print_r($news_items);

        //display looping judul, content
        foreach ($news_items as $item)
        {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $item->title.' - '.$item->content;
            echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

model:

```
function get_all()
{
    $this->db->select('
        id_post,
        title,
        content,
        post_date,
    ');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->order_by('YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date)', 'asc');

    $hasil = $this->db->get();
    if( $hasil->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $news_array = array();
        foreach($hasil->result() as $arsip){

            $time_period = date("F Y", strtotime($arsip->post_date));
            if (!isset($news_array[$time_period]))
            {
              // buat sub array kalo butuh
              $news_array[$time_period] = array();
            }
            $news_array[$time_period][] = $arsip;
        }
        return $news_array;
    }
}
```

any idea how to create the pagination base on year? please..

Regards.

Comment: @Jason B i see, sorry for the title, thanks

Comment: No problem! Just doing the job as moderator

Comment: why dont you add a year parameter on models `get_all()` method and add a where by `year`? You can create pagination link by years and get year from `uri_string`, like `?year=2013`

Answer (score 0):

You should send a `year` parameter to your model and add where condition by YEAR on sql. You can get `year` from get input.

Your Controller;

```
$this->load->model('model_test');
$year = $this->input->get('year');
$arsip = $this->model_test->get_all($year);
...
```

Your Model;

```
 function get_all($year = null){
    $this->db->select('id_post,title,content,post_date');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    if (null !== $year){
        $this->db->where('YEAR(date(post_date))', $year)
    }

    $this->db->order_by('YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date)', 'asc');

    $hasil = $this->db->get();
    if( $hasil->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $news_array = array();
        foreach($hasil->result() as $arsip){

            $time_period = date("F Y", strtotime($arsip->post_date));
            if (!isset($news_array[$time_period]))
            {
             // buat sub array kalo butuh
             $news_array[$time_period] = array();
            }
           $news_array[$time_period][] = $arsip;
        }
       return $news_array;
     }
 }
```

Your View;

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?year=2013">2013</a></li>
  <li><a href="?year=2014">2015</a></li>
  <li><a href="?year=2015">2015</a></li>
  <li><a href="?year=2016">2016</a></li>
  <li><a href="?year=2017">2017</a></li>
</ul>
```